# Activity orientation based on res value

Tags: android

Is there a way to define screen orientation **in the manifest** based on a stored res value?

For example:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="@integer/screenOrientation"
...
```

I want to lock the orientation to portrait for phones but not for tablets.  I'm doing this in code but there's a brief period prior to execution where the app appears in landscape on phones then snaps to portrait.  Looking to avoid this.

Hoping I could use a value in integers or strings and just put them in the required dimen folder

If possible, I've been unable to find values for the available orientation options, could someone provide those?

thank you so much!

Comment: For your first part of the question, you can check if it is tablet or smartphone programmatically then set the orientation, but I am not sure that I got the other parts of your question

Comment: @Cergo I know we can do it programmatically.  We're already doing that.  But there's a delay between app launch and code execution and it just doesn't look good.  Looking for a way to accomplish this in the manifest

Comment: Can you provide your current code? it could be helpful to take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Constant for {@link #orientation}: a value indicating that no value has been set. */
public static final int ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED = 0;
/** Constant for {@link #orientation}, value corresponding to the
 * <a href="{@docRoot}guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#OrientationQualifier">port</a>
 * resource qualifier. */
public static final int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT = 1;
/** Constant for {@link #orientation}, value corresponding to the
 * <a href="{@docRoot}guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#OrientationQualifier">land</a>
 * resource qualifier. */
public static final int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 2;
```

[Check the available configuration](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4_r1/core/java/android/content/res/Configuration.java)